# Scala get JSON value in a specific data type on map object

Tags: json, scala, jackson

Using *jackson* library I read json data from a file (each row of file is a JSON object) an parse it to a map object of *String* and *Any*. My goal is to save specified keys (id and text) to a collection.

```
val input = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.json").getLines()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with DefaultScalaModule
val data_collection = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, String]

for (i <- input){
      val parsedJson = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Any]](i)
      data_collection.put(
        parsedJson.get("id"),
        parsedJson.get("text")
      )
```

But as the values in the *parsedJson* map have the *Any* type, getting some keys like *id* and *text*, it returns *Some(value)* not just the value with the appropriate type. I expect the values for the *id* key to be Integer and values for the *text* to be String.
Running the code I got the error:

```
Error:(31, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Any]
 required: Int
        parsedJson.get("id"),
```

Here is a sample of JSON data in the file:

```
{"text": "Hello How are you", "id": 1}
```

Is it possible in Scala to parse id values to Int and text values to String, or at least convert Some(value) to value with type Int or String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a plain value from a `Map` instead of a **Option** you can use the `()` (`apply`) method - However it will throw an exception if the key is not found.

Second, Scala type system is static not dynamic, if you have an `Any` that's it, it won't change to `Int` or `String` at runtime, and the compiler will fail - Nevertheless, you can cast them using the `asInstanceOf[T]` method, but again if type can't be casted to the target type it will throw an exception.

Please note that even if you can make your code work with the above tricks, that code wouldn't be what you would expect in Scala. There are ways to make the code more typesafe *(like pattern matching)*, but parsing a Json to a typesafe object is an old problem, I'm sure jackson provides a way to parse a json into **case class** that represent your data. If not take a look to [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) it does.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import 
 com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val input = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.json").getLines() 
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val obj = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Any]](input)
val data_collection = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, String]
for (i <- c) {
data_collection.put(
  obj.get("id").fold(0)(_.toString.toInt),
  obj.get("text").fold("")(_.toString)
 )
 }
println(data_collection) // Map(1 -> Hello How are you)
```

Comment: I had tried the `object`. It causes the error, too. `Error:(27, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Object]
 required: Int
        parsedJson.get("id"),`

Comment: Hey, I add the definition of the `mapper` object in the code.

Comment: could you please paste your all imports as  well

Comment: @soheil-pourbafrani I have edited my answer and it is working fine for me, I have taken text from a string you can replace your file reading code.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani please accept the answer if it helped you or let me know I can dig more